# How to Subclass using UITableViewDelegate - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, subclass

Lets say I have an `Open` class called `MyClass`, which exists inside a framework. This class does other things, but also includes the implementation of a UITableView...

`Open` being the new `Public`, means i should be able to access the class from within another module, and subclass it. Here is an example class below:

```
open class TableViewEngine: NSObject {

   internal var tableView: UITableView!

   public init(tableView: UITableView) {
       super.init()
       self.tableView = tableView
       self.setupTableView()
   }

   fileprivate func setupTableView() {
       self.tableView.delegate = self
       self.tableView.dataSource = self
       self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
   }
}

extension TableViewEngine: UITableViewDataSource {
   public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       return UITableViewCell()
   }
}
```

Now, lets say I want to subclass MyClass, and add additions UITableViewDelegates

```
public CustomClass: MyClass {

   e.g./// heightForRow

}
```

My problem is that CustomClass never calls these newly additional delegates added, because they are defined in the UITableViewDelegate by Apple as **public rather than open**, so they are never actually called (although they are predicted when writing).

This used to work before Swift 3, before they introduced **Open**.

How do i get around this?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment